# How to get PyCharm to automatically recognize Django template directories?

Tags: django, pycharm

In PyCharm 3.0, you can manually specify individual directories as being template directories, which allows the system to recognize template filename references within Python code.

My question is -- is there any way to tell it that all directories named "template" are template directories?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such feature. However, for Django applications, PyCharm can automatically parse settings.py and find template directories according to the settings there, so manual configuration shouldn't be required.